# How to get the $<Vf, g>$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

> For $f=e^{-x}$, how to check $f$ solving the following equation
>   $$(-\Delta-V)f=Cf, x\in R^n$$
>   for some constants.

What we need to check is that $$<(-\Delta-V)f, g>=<Cf, g>:=\int_{R^3} Cfg$$
for all test functions $g$.

I am stuck in how to compute
$$<(-V)f, g>$$ and I have got $<(-\Delta f, g>=<Cf, g>$. So I hope $<(-V)f, g>=0$

Comment: Are you working in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: @CameronWilliams No, just $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint (to get you started):** Well $x \mapsto e^{-|x|}$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, so that 
$$
\Delta e^{-|x|} = \textrm{div}(\nabla e^{-|x|})
$$

and we trivially have that $\nabla e^{-|x|} = -\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot e^{-|x|}$. Moreover,
and we have the well-known identity for $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$  that
$$
\textrm{div}(f(x)V(x)) = \nabla f(x) \cdot V(x) + f(x) \textrm{div}(V(x)).
$$

Comment: well, I have got $\Delta e^{-|x|}$. But how to deal with $<(-1/|x|)f, g>$?

Comment: Well, what did you find for $\Delta e^{-|x|}$ ? Can't you go from there ?

Comment: I just get $<-\Delta e^{-|x|}, g>=<Ce^{-|x|}, g>$.

Comment: That's a mistake; you should do the computations again ;-)

Comment: Sorry, do you mean $\Delta (x/|x| )=1/|x|$?  So term $(-1/|x|) fg$ in the integral will cancel?

Comment: Yes exactly, at some point the terms should cancel each others !

Comment: But why $\Delta(x/|x|)=1/|x|$? Is it not the delta function?

Comment: I was saying that at some point terms will canceled, but $\Delta(x/|x|)$ doesn't mean anything (since $x/|x| \in \mathbb{R}^3$). Do the computation of $\Delta e^{-|x|}$ slowly and you will see that a term in $1/|x|$ pops up :-) ! (NB : I think that there should be a $2$ in front of $1/|x|$ in your equation, but I'm not sure, I haven't done the computations myself)

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\nabla (x/|x|)$. I do not know how to compute it. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Well, you can come back to the definition and compute $\partial_{x_k} x/|x|$ for every $k$ ! Try, and let me know if you cannot do it ;)

Comment: I guess the result is $1/|x|$ but I compute $\partial_{x_1} x/|x|$ which is $(|x|^2-x_1^2)/|x|^3$.

Comment: So here your $f=-x/|x|$ and we need to compute $div(-x/|x|)$, right? But this is zeor...

Comment: No, this is not zero; you should use the formula above : $\textrm{div}(x/|x|) = \nabla (1 / |x|) \cdot x + \text{div}(x) / |x|$, and $\textrm{div}(x) = 3$...

Comment: So that is $-|x|^{1/2}+3/|x|$?

Comment: well, there is still a wired term $|x|^{1/2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I see.. thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106499/discussion-between-bob-oakley-and-hermes).